# What is the motivation for $R$-algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebras

Dummit & Foote makes the following definition:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. An **$\mathbf R$-algebra** is a ring $A$ with identity together with a ring homomorphism $f:R\to A$ mapping $1_R$ to $1_A$ such that the subring $f(R)$ of $A$ is contained in the center of $A$.

I understand the definition, and see some examples (any ring with identity is a $\mathbb Z$-algebra, the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is an $R$-algebra, etc.) but I am not really seeing the motivation behind this definition. Why are we interested in this object? To contrast, I can see modules over rings as a generalization of vector spaces over fields (the former of which I am not too familiar with, the latter of which I am fairly familiar with). But this definition just seems a bit artificial and I am not comfortable with it.

Also, I assume there are other types of "algebras," since there is made a distinction here that this is an $R$-algebra. Is it the case that there is a general structure called an "algebra", and this is a specific type of an algebra? I do remember from my operator theory class that there were Banach and $C^*$-algebras - are these also "algebras" in the sense of the algebraic structure?

Comment: They are algebras in the sense of the algebraic structure. They are $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ algebras. There are several very general notions of an "algebra." But they don't seem to be directly related to this definition imo, being formalizations of the idea of an "algebraic structure" mostly.

Comment: You can think of “algebras” as generalization of modules, in which there is a way to “multiply” elements of the algebra with one another, in addition to knowing to multiply them by the elements of your coefficient ring. Note the quaternions are $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, for example. As to other “algebras”, the point is that the “coefficient ring” is important. It’s more like talking about $k$-vector spaces (as opposed to just vector sapce) or $R$-modules (as opposed to just “modules”).. The general structure called an algebra is something more general and really separate from this.

Comment: At first algebra is about polynomials. $R$-algebra is what you need to look at $P(a)$ for $a\in A$ and $P\in R[x]$.

Comment: In algebraic topology, you often have graded/differential algebras which are composed of modules over the ground ring. Many standard examples: chain complex on a loop space, etc, are naturally occurring examples of algebras over a ring. I think the usefulness of a definition is partially measured by the number and variety of examples. I don't necessarily think that's what D&F have in mind, but that's just my perspective on why algebras over a ring is a natural idea to think about.

Comment: @JustinYoung Thanks, I am actually studying algebra mostly to prepare for studying algebraic topology, so your comment is very helpful.